# Unable to create a View that lists all "Locations," alongside number of "departments" and number of "employees" in those departments

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

I'm just generally rubbish with SQL (knowing how to complete the most basic of tasks - still learning) and require the guidance of an experienced person who may be able to explain the processes behind the correct solution to my problem.

As the title implies, I'm tasked with creating a view that lists all the Locations, alongside them the number of departments in each location, and finally the number of people employed at each location.

Sorry for any formatting errors that may follow. I'm pretty new here.

The following 2 tables (Dept and Emp) should provide all the information needed:

**Emp**

```
 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM    DEPTNO
 ----- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------------------
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                   20
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300        30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500        30
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                   20
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400        30
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                   30
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                   10
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                   20
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                   10
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0        30
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                   20
  7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                   30
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                   20
  7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                   10
```

**Dept**

```
DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
------ -------------- -------------
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
    30 SALES          CHICAGO
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

I know what I need to get to, but I don't really have much of an idea of how to get there.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me here. Appreciated.

Well, with what I've been told so far I've got this:

```
SELECT Dept.Loc "Location", Emp.Ename "Emp count", Emp.deptno "Dept count"
COUNT(DISTINCT Emp.Ename) AND (DISTINCT Emp.Deptno)
FROM Emp;
```

Not sure if I'm going in the right way or not. It's really frustrating.

Comment: usually you post your best try. not just ask for someone to do it for you.  start with writing SELECT and then a join...

Comment: You're right. But the truth is, I'm unsure where to start. I'll keep trying to see what I can come up with

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` to get the result.  Please start writing a `SELECT` statement and post your try.

Comment: As of right now, I have the following:

SELECT Dept.Loc "Location", Emp.Ename "Emp count", Emp.deptno "Dept count"
COUNT(

Am I heading in the right direction here?

Comment: God damn this is frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, figure out how to JOIN the two tables into one big table, so you new table has all of the columns from both tables.

CLUE:   Look up JOIN and use the DEPTNO field

```
select * 
from Emp
join Dept on emp.deptNo=Dept.deptNo
```

Now, GROUP BY this result by Location, Department name

```
select Loc,dName,count(*)
from Emp
    join Dept on emp.deptNo=Dept.deptNo
group by loc,dName
```

This should get your started.

You are actually pretty close, by tweak your query with the JOIN and GROUP BY example above

To create a view, do

```
CREATE VIEW  myViewName AS
 SELECT statement
```

Comment: Thanks. I've come up with the following:

SELECT Loc, dName, Ename, Count(*)
FROM Emp
JOIN Dept on Emp.Deptno=Dept.Deptno
GROUP BY Dept.Loc;

But it returns an error saying that something in line 1 is not a GROUP BY expression. I'm jammed.

Comment: Every field in the select clause must be also in the group by.  Take out eName from the select list and add dName to the group by

Comment: All right, I understand that now, thanks. Is this the answer? There's only one department per location, and the numbers depict how many people are working in each department, so... Yay? Edit: Oh but wait, it asks for a View to be made. How do I turn this into a View command?

Comment: The View is typically something like      CREATE VIEW name AS followed by your SELECT statement.      Depends on what version of SQL you are using, Oracle,SQL-Server, mySQL, etc.

Comment: I'm using sqlplus. Oh forgot to mention - I need to include the 4th area which is Boston, but it wasn't listed in results since nobody works there. I have no idea how to make it appear in this case.

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN instead of a JOIN.

Comment: Thanks. I'd already tried this, but the 4th row still is not appearing. Here's the command again for reference: SELECT Loc, Dname, Count(*)
FROM Emp
LEFT JOIN Dept ON Emp.Deptno=Dept.Deptno
GROUP BY Loc, Dname;

Comment: Reverse the DEPT and Emp tables.    (I.E.  Select FROM Dept and JOIN on Emp)

Comment: Thanks. That kind-of fixed it. Problem is now that the 4th row is now showing, but as 1 and not 0. This is so tedious! Here's the edited command: SELECT Loc, Dname, Count(*)
FROM Dept
LEFT JOIN Emp ON Dept.Deptno=Emp.Deptno
GROUP BY Loc, Dname;

Comment: Change the count(*) to count(DeptNo)

Comment: Thanks once again. I changed it to Count(Emp.Deptno) and it worked perfectly. Sorry I can't give you an arrow up yet, but I do appreciate your patience and time.